# Npm gives depreciated errors when trying to install firebase tools for flutter

Tags: firebase, npm, npm-install

I get the following when I run "npm install -g firebase-tools" on Node.js command prompt.

```
C:\Users\DELL>npm install -g firebase-tools
npm WARN deprecated har-validator@5.1.3: this library is no longer supported
npm WARN deprecated debug@4.1.0: Debug versions >=3.2.0 <3.2.7 || >=4 <4.3.1 have a low-severity ReDos regression when used in a Node.js environment. It is recommended you upgrade to 3.2.7 or 4.3.1. (https://github.com/visionmedia/debug/issues/797)
npm WARN deprecated debug@4.1.1: Debug versions >=3.2.0 <3.2.7 || >=4 <4.3.1 have a low-severity ReDos regression when used in a Node.js environment. It is recommended you upgrade to 3.2.7 or 4.3.1. (https://github.com/visionmedia/debug/issues/797)
npm WARN deprecated uuid@3.4.0: Please upgrade  to version 7 or higher.  Older versions may use Math.random() in certain circumstances, which is known to be problematic.  See https://v8.dev/blog/math-random for details.
npm WARN deprecated request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142

changed 687 packages, and audited 688 packages in 2m

35 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

21 vulnerabilities (15 moderate, 6 high)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I decided to ignore the depreciated errors and continue with the further steps in installation and I was able to complete the firebase installation.

Comment: idk, I have the same error, but when I try to run a command in the package, it says "command not found"

Comment: Did you add the location of npm to the path ? @Baha

Answer (score 0):

try `npm cache verify`, then try again

Comment: Hii, Thank you @gavin  I tried your method. But I'm still facing the same issue.

Comment: try to install npm new version. command: `npm install -g npm`

Comment: Hii, I  installed Node package manager just got the purpose of installating the above mentioned tools. So immediately after installing npm , I ran the command. Plus I saw one guy on YouTube just ignore the Depreciated error and proceed with the installation, so I did the same and everything works properly.  Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Try to install using:

```bash
curl -sL https://firebase.tools | bash
```

Worked for me.